DaisyUI Navbar Not Responsive: Hamburger Menu Not Appearing on Smaller Screens
I'm using DaisyUI with Tailwind CSS in a React TypeScript project. I've implemented a Navbar component, but it's not responsive as expected. The hamburger menu doesn't appear on smaller screens, and the horizontal navbar doesn't hide on smaller or medium screens.
Problem

The hamburger menu icon doesn't show up on smaller screens.
The horizontal navbar doesn't hide on smaller or medium screens; it just compacts.

import React from "react";
import '../../App.css'

export const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar bg-base-100">
      <div className="navbar-start">
        {/* Hamburger menu for small screens */}
        <div className="dropdown">
          <button tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-ghost lg:hidden">
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              className="h-5 w-5"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              stroke="currentColor">
              <path
                strokeLinecap="round"
                strokeLinejoin="round"
                strokeWidth="2"
                d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <ul
            tabIndex={0}
            className="menu menu-sm dropdown-content bg-base-100 rounded-box z-[1] mt-3 w-52 p-2 shadow">
            <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
            <li>
              <a>Parent</a>
              <ul className="p-2">
                <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        {/* Logo or Brand */}
        <a className="btn btn-ghost text-xl">daisyUI</a>
      </div>
      {/* Horizontal menu for large screens */}
      <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex">
        <ul className="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li>
            <details>
              <summary>Parent</summary>
              <ul className="p-2">
                <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </details>
          </li>
          <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-end">
        <a className="btn">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Expected Behavior

The horizontal navbar should hide on smaller and medium screens and be replaced by a hamburger menu.
The hamburger menu should be clickable to show a dropdown menu on smaller and medium screens.

Current Behavior

The horizontal navbar remains visible and just gets compacted on smaller and medium screens.
The hamburger menu doesn't appear on smaller screens.

Attempts to Fix

Tailwind CSS Configuration: Verified that Tailwind CSS and DaisyUI are properly configured and imported.
Class Adjustments: Tried using block lg:hidden for the hamburger menu and hidden lg:flex for the horizontal menu.
CSS Debugging: Used browser developer tools to inspect elements and verify the applied classes.


Can you use the DOM inspector and see what CSS styles might be overwriting your classnames there, or at least to see if they are being applied and overwritten vs. something else preventing them from being rendered at all? If I test this in isolation with Tailwind and a non-React implementation (replacing className with just class) it works as expected.

I am using a React implementation in this project. Since you referenced isolation. I added storybook to isolate the component and work on it.

For starters, you probably want your lg:hidden to be on the dropdown component not just the SVG icon, as that will hide the icon only – not the dropdown. Next, the rest of your problem must lay elsewhere, either something that isn't being rendered properly somewhere else in your component tree, or perhaps CSS that is clobbering your styles. Without more details, though, it's going to be impossible to pinpoint further than that. I'd suggest using the DOM inspector to try and trace whether the styles are being set a at all, and if they're being clobbered, what might be doing that.
Here's a non-React (vanilla HTML) on Tailwind Play that shows more/less what you're expecting, working:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/2738Ysjx3w
<div class="navbar-start">
  <div class="dropdown lg:hidden">
    <!-- All I've changed here is moving ^ hidden up a level -->
    <button tabIndex={0} class="btn btn-ghost">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="black">
        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <ul tabIndex={0} class="menu menu-sm dropdown-content bg-base-100 rounded-box z-[1] mt-3 w-52 p-2 shadow">
      <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
      <li>
        <a>Parent</a>
        <ul class="p-2">
          <li><a>Submenu 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="btn btn-ghost text-xl">daisyUI</a>
</div>

